# the correct way to use nornir plugins

Tags: python-3.x, automation, netmiko

I am a beginner with nornir, I am trying to run nornir plugins but I am having these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nornirpy/start.py", line 2, in <module>
    from nornir.plugins.tasks.commands import commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nornir.plugins.tasks.commands'
```

My start.py file is very basic:

```
from nornir import InitNornir
from nornir.plugins.tasks.commands import commands
from nornir.core.inventory import Host
from path.to import InventoryPlugin
import json

nr = InitNornir("nornirpy/config.yml")

print(json.dumps(Host.schema(), indent=4))
```

What is the issue? I am using poetry to organize my project, is there a step I forgot? its not clear to me how can I use plugins in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Somayyah Mohammed;

First, check the version of nornir you are using. If version > 2.4.0 then module `nornir.plugins.tasks.commands` is not there. You can remove the import command it should work.